# Android - How to deselect all tabs in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using an ActionBar with tabs in my app, along with an old fashioned menu. When you go into the fragment associated with the menu item, I'd like to keep the ActionBar visible, but deselect all the tabs.

I tried:

```
_actionBar.selectTab(null);
```

But that throws an exception.

PS I'm actually using the ActionBarSherlock for compatibility, if that makes a difference.

Comment: getActionBar().removeAllTabs();

Comment: No, I don't want to remove the tabs; I just don't want any of them to appear selected.

Comment: @K_Anas  getActionBar().removeAllTabs() will just remove all tabs completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could not deselect tab, what do you think will happen? One of tabs should be always selected.

Think about your users. They will not expect that behavior.

Comment: OK, at least I know that's the limitation of the system. I didn't come up with the UX for this app, I'm just trying to implement the design as provided. Thanks.

Comment: I think he means he needs a root, with tabs on top. Selecting the tab pushes the fragment on top of the root. Root has no tabs selected. I have the same problem.

Answer (score 8):

Then catch it :)

I just tested this, it works, the blue underline under the tab disappears which is exactly what I want to do too.

```
       try {
          ActionBar actionbar = (ActionBar) getActionBar();
          actionbar.selectTab(null);
       } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Program flow carries on....it's a work around.

Comment: Clever. I will definitely try this (next time).

Comment: Throws a runtime exception

Comment: For me using the Android Support Library (and therefore using `getSupportActionBar()`), this threw a NullPointerException, which was then caught, but then the blue line selection bar was still there. So no Action Bar tab became unselected... Overall, nothing actually happened.

Comment: Works perfectly. It is probably worth pointing out that this answer is relevant to monodroid (xamarin) only. The original question is asked for native android.

Answer (score 2):

> How to deselect all tabs in the ActionBar

You don't. A tab is always selected.

Comment: why is this true.  I have a screen for searching.  I have a nearby tab, and a Favorites tab.  If the user hits the search icon above it, and it brings back results, then I want neither tab selected.  Yes, I could add a third tab into it.  But I could also just deselect both, and to the user, it looks like expected.

Comment: @WallMobile: "then I want neither tab selected" -- your user does. "Yes, I could add a third tab into it" -- the user is going to think that your app has a bug if the user does a search and you do not show any results. Talented programmers, therefore, show search results when the user does a search. Either show the results in an existing tab (which should be selected), add a third tab (which should be selected), or show the results in a new activity (which has no tabs).

Comment: possibly.  i am working throuigh what will look best for the user now.  If they get back no results I would give a message.  I see your point, but need to work through the process a bit to find the best user experience.

Comment: @WallMobile: "If they get back no results I would give a message" -- a crouton is one way to represent that, in a way that does not have to permanently disrupt the rest of your UI structure. https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton and http://johnkil.github.io/Android-AppMsg/ are popular solutions.

Comment: thanks, update your post so that i can remove the -1.  got a little trigger happy :)  I think I am going to go with the open a new activity route.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm necromancing right now... but I found a solution that works.  So just in case someone else is trying to do this, here you go.

You just create a dummy tab and never add it to the action bar.  Select the dummy tab and the Tabs in the action bar are all NOT selected.  The dummy will have an index of -1 if you debug the `onTabSelected` etc methods of the `ActionBar.TabListener`.

Note:  This assumes you are implementing `ActionBar.TabListener` in your `Activity`.

```
String tabTitles[] = {"A", "B"};
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

for (String tabName : tabTitles) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabName).setTabListener(this), false);  
}

ActionBar.Tab dummyTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Dummy").setTabListener(this);

try{
    actionBar.selectTab(dummnyTab);
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

Save a copy of your default color state list for selected and unselected text colors

```
val tabStateTextColors = tabLayout.tabTextColors
```

Set tab selected indicator to transparent

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getColor(android.R.color.transparent))
```

Set text colors for unselected state

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getColor(R.color.gray),getColor(R.color.gray))
```

Reset colors back when you want to go back to normal

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(tabStateTextColors)
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getColor(R.color.black)
```

So the general gist of this is to set the corresponding colors so it looks like the tab is not selected.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a **TabLayout**. As a workaround, I first set the selected tab indicator color to transparent:

```
int colorTransparent = getColor(R.color.transparent);
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(colorTransparent);
```

and hid the ViewPager/content - so it basically looked like nothing was selected with no current page visible.

Then, when the user presses the button, I changed the selected tab indicator color back to `R.color.accent` and faded in the ViewPager/content.